# P-Asserted-Identity vs history info

Tags: sip, voip

I'm newbie in SIP field. So, please forgive if there is old/easy questions.

Please take a basic call-flow as below to analysis.

```
phone A -- calls  -- phone B -- (transfer to ) -- phone C
```

A, B, C are extension on same PBX.

Question 1. So, in INVITE message, the History-info will contain:

```
 At B

 `History-info : <sip: user A @domain.com>`

At C:

 `History-info : <sip: user A @domain.com>`

 `History-info : <sip: user B @domain.com>`

 `History-info : <sip: user C @domain.com>`
```

Question 2. And, the PAI header will generate in INVITE message of C

and the format is :

`P-Asserted-Identity: <sip:user A @domain;user=phone>.`

Question 3. I just want to know when does 2 SIP headers: History-info and P-Asserted-Identity (PAI) occur in SIP message ? and which case ?

Question 4. The difference between 2 SIP headers above and the purpose of them. Are they generated on INVITE message or others ?

Please help me make these concerns clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Not sure what the question is, but if all UAs (extensions) are sending the calls through the PBX, the PBX may add the History-info fields in any request not associated with an established dialog (INVITE, REGISTER, MESSAGE, REFER and OPTIONS, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE, ..)

Q2: The PAI field should be set with the identity of the calling party, which is still extension A for internal calls. In another scenario, like A is calling B and B is redirected to an outside line, the PAI might be overwritten by the PBX with B's outbound number before the call is sent through the external SIP trunk.

Q3: History-info (RFC4244) is an application specific header field, not always present and most commonly injected by your PBX for internal reasons (checking routing, detecting redirect loops, charging, etc). Being an optional field, its availability and purpose in extensions may vary.
PAI field (RFC3325) contains the identity of the caller.

Q4: Q3 explains the difference between them, PAI holds the identity while histinfo fields are holding the indexed tracking of SIP URIs through which the message passed and any additional info.
PAI can appear in INVITE/OPTIONS/SUBSCRIBE/NOTIFY, for histinfo see Q1.